# Can connect to router, but cannot access server (but only on my PC)

Tags: vpn, troubleshooting

Using Windows Pro 64, I have been VPN-ing to our work server for years.  Now, I can still connect to the router OK, but when I do I cannot access the server.  When I map a network drive, I get 'Windows cannot access \servername\resource'. I've turned off the firewall & anti-virus, but no difference. I can ping the IP server OK.  I tried a different PC, with absolutely no problem, so there  seems to be something wrong on my specific PC.  But I've run out of places to look!  Can anybody help?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with credentials then a network problem. I would suggest this post be moved to SuperUser.

But just a stab in the dark, are you connecting to multiple Domains? That is, you are locally on one Domain and the VPN is another Domain (that you do not authenticate against).

Comment: Not connected to multiple domains, no.  BTW the Windows error msg is 0x80070035 which appears to be a common problem.

Comment: Also, I tried some different, working credentials when trying to map the network drive.  Same error.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions here: http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000439.htm

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found in the comment by ojs:

*Have you tried any of the suggestions here: petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000439.htm –  ojs*

I ran the two 'netsh' commands, restarted after each command & now I can map a network drive again.  My remaining question is, of course, what went wrong that meant I had to do this?  But thanks ojs I am very grateful!